# How to get videos from designated album

Tags: ios

I'm trying to get an mp4 file from an album, but I don't want to get it all;
I just want a part of that, like just the Horizontal mp4 file or just one album's VIDEO, not all of that.
Usually, I just use

```
// 2 - Get image picker
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

// 3 - Display image picker
[controller presentViewController:mediaUI animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So I can get an simple view to chose my video, but now I need to get an array or dictionary, which have all videos from a designated album.

Comment: You could use ALAsset Library. There is an Apple's Sample.

Comment: @larme, that's a little later,but thank you , and when i reading about ALAsset, i found PHAssetCollection, come from Photos framework, it's the new api since iOS 8.0, and now i'm learning how to use it.